# Feature Selection for Mass spectrometry data

Tags: machine-learning, svm, feature-selection

I have a cancer patients data from mass spectrometry which consists of more than half million features and my task is to apply feature selection algorithm to extract the most relevant features from it. My question is which feature selection model would me more appropriate in this case... Any suggestions will be more appreciated...

Comment: It is better to ask your question [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: "My question is which feature selection model would be more appropriate in this case", what have you considered so far? Tell us your approach so far

Comment: @ABear I have an idea of implementing any filter to the dataset or to apply Random Forest algorithm which consists of in built Feature Selection. But Prior to know the more available procedures for huge datasets

Answer (score 0):

Use a support vector machine, a type of machine learning model. Perhaps Python and Tensorflow would be useful here!

All the best,

OL